# The versafix-1 template on the mosaico site has editing options I don't see in civi. Any chance of getting them?

Tags: mosaico

I'm trying to get my users off of creating an email in mailchimp and importing the html into civi.  Mosaico seems to fit the bill.  I showed it to the main user today and, of course, they had issues.  Mainly with centering of things.

I later went and looked at the template in the mosaico site, https://mosaico.io/ and noticed that there are more editing options there than in the implementation on civi.

So the question is do I have something set wrong so I'm missing these or is there a later version of the versafix-1 template out there that just hasn't been upgraded yet in civi?

Examples of options not available in civi.  If you pick the block with an image at the top, a title below it, body text below that and a button (the third block from the top of the list of bocks), there is an option to pick the size of the image.  The image is centered (in civi, it's left justified), you can edit the style and center the title, center the button.

Using mosaico extension version 2.0-beta4.1528762072.  I'm not using shoreditch.  I couldn't get it to work and since it says it optional...

Comment: curious to know what about shoreditch you couldn't get to work.

Comment: I think it actually does work.  It's just that the mailing stuff is so different from what it was that I thought it was missing things.  Plus, I hadn't figured out yet when I was testing this that traditional mailings are a different menu options so I originally thought it was missing stuff there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

we're looking to upgrade the mosaico library in CiviCRM to the latest version in the next few weeks. After we do that the extra features will become available.

Comment: I have noticed the same difference today. How can I use the versafluid template?

Answer (score 2):

Much of what you're looking to do can now be done via an extension.  There's an extension that's not pretty but does the trick called [Mosaico Toolbar Config](https://github.com/ginkgostreet/com.ginkgostreet.mosaicotoolbarconfig) from Ginkgo Street Labs.